# How to split check all that apply choice survey answers but keep variable levels with the person's identifier

Tags: r

I am doing a military mental health survey that has check all that apply questions in it. When a person has multiple answers to one question, how do I split the levels but keep them with the same identifier?

For examply my variable DADT has the levels Before, During, and After. Some people have selected all three choices or two choices. I want to build a mosaic plot comparing DADT to service members gender identity. I the mosiac plot represent three catigories for DADT and not seven catigories.

I would like to continue having the levels split for analys against other variables.

```r
zz <- "ID   Branch.Service DADT                 Birth.Gender Gender.Identity
1       1      Navy,Army   Before                  Yes          Male
2       2      Navy        After                   Yes          Male
4       3      Marines     Before,During,After     Yes          Male
5       4      Navy        After                   No           Non-binary
6       5      Airforce    During                  Yes          Female

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Expected output for the data shared would have been helpful to know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? It uses the separate_rows function from tidyr to make new rows for each element of a comma separated list of values in a column.

```
zz <- "ID   Branch.Service DADT                 Birth.Gender Gender.Identity
1       1      Navy,Army   Before                  Yes          Male
2       2      Navy        After                   Yes          Male
4       3      Marines     Before,During,After     Yes          Male
5       4      Navy        After                   No           Non-binary
6       5      Airforce    During                  Yes          Female"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)

Data <- tidyr::separate_rows(Data, Branch.Service, DADT, sep = ",")

     ID Branch.Service DADT   Birth.Gender Gender.Identity
  <int> <chr>          <chr>  <fct>        <fct>          
1     1 Navy           Before Yes          Male           
2     1 Army           Before Yes          Male           
3     2 Navy           After  Yes          Male           
4     3 Marines        Before Yes          Male           
5     3 Marines        During Yes          Male           
6     3 Marines        After  Yes          Male           
7     4 Navy           After  No           Non-binary     
8     5 Airforce       During Yes          Female
```